# Reporting Services: come back from the sub-report to parent report and have it auto-run

Tags: ssrs-2012, subreport

The environment is SQL Server Reporting Services 2012.  I have two reporting services reports: parent report lists some records and those records are presented and hyperlinks.  These hyperlinks can be clicked and this will take you to a child report (for the clicked record).  I also pass some parameters as part of the call to the child report and everything works fine.

On the child report I have a text box, which is a link back to parent report.  I configured "Action" property for this text box to pass some parameters back (from the child report to the parent report).  The problem is that after clicking "Back to Parent" link, the parent report doesn't automatically render.  I have to select my parameters manually and click "View report" button in order to make it run.

How can I make parent report auto-render when I navigate back to it from the child report?

Comment: It sounds like one of the parameters isn't being populated with a default value or value from the action.  It would be helpful to see which parameters are blank, their default values, and the action that navigates back.  There are certainly options - if needed you can use a hidden "Autofill" parameter that's only set to true by the subreport and have the other parameters cascade off of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, bitnine, for your input!  I do have somewhat complicated parameters in my report, some of which are cascaded. I had to ensure that all of them either had defaults specified or had values provided by the "Action" mapping (as specified on the sub-report's "Back to Parent" link.  After that, things started working as expected.